# What should I do about [NeutralResourceLanguage] to get my app accepted?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

My WP app has been failed because of  [NeutralResourceLanguage]. And they send as  a message

> make sure to check the [NeutralResourceLanguage] attribute on the entry assembly

I don't understand what I am supposed to do exactly. Can you help me about what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the default culture for your app.

Look here for more Informations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=VS.92).aspx